# Starting Activities in a looping chain

Tags: android

I have three Activities, which are started in a chain. ActivityA starts ActivityB, which then starts ActivityC. I also have an Application object.

ActivityA starts ActivityB with (this snippet is actually in an anonymous class, so it needs `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`).

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class));
```

ActivityB starts ActivityC with

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityC.class));
```

In ActivityC, if the user wants to go back to ActivityA, he will click a Button that invokes

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), ActivityA.class));
```

My question is, is this the correct way to do this while avoiding memory leaks?

Comment: More information about what your Activities do would be helpful to optimize the process for your app (i.e., whether you want to use, instead, `startActivityForResult()` or set a flag on the Intent to maintain only one version of the Activity in the stack.

Comment: ActivityA is a ListView that represents the main menu of the application. From the main menu, if the user clicks a certain item, it starts ActivityB, a PreferenceActivity. Only after going through ActivityB, will the user be allowed to see ActivityC. From ActivityC, I want to allow the user to go back to the main menu, but this main menu obviously shouldn't be duplicated in multiple instances. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: I'll just leave this in a comment since I don't have a full solution, but you'll want to add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);` to the `Intent` that takes the user back to ActivityA.  The problem is that the Back button will take the user back to ActivityC, then ActivityB, then out of the app, which I assume is undesirable.  I'm still working on manipulating the stack correctly in my app.

Comment: It was helpful to know about the Intent activity flags. I found that `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` combined with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` (or `android:launchMode="singleTop"`) did the trick.

Comment: I read through those yesterday and didn't even notice that flag.  That's exactly what I needed as well, so +1 for your comment as well as the question.

Answer (score 0):

It could be, but I recommend to use

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

in your manifest for your activities.

And, generally speaking, don't forget activties are stacked by android already, but you right, sometimes this stacking mechanism isn't flexible enough.

Stéphane

Comment: Good tip, but I found it better to use that in combination with the intent flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.